# Can I call anonymous self-invoking function from different scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using ReactJS. I want to call hello() function. I got "Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined" error. How can I fix it?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="sample.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      var CommentBox = React.createClass({
        handleClick: function(){
          console.log(hello());
        },
        render: function() {
          return (
            <a onClick={this.handleClick}>click me</a>
          );
        }
      });
      ReactDOM.render(
        <CommentBox />,
        document.getElementById('content')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

sample.js

```
$(function(){
  function hello() {
    return "Hi";
  }
});
```

Comment: why do yo need to wrap it with `$()` ?

Comment: Hi. We have many anonymous self-invoking functions already that why I want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Thanks

```
var O = (function(){
  function hello() {
    return "Hi";
  }
  return {hello: hello};
})();
```

```
handleClick: function(){
  console.log(O.hello());
}
```